# Wordpress returning rest_api value for all _links

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a wordpress site where I rely on a lot of embedded data in posts, such as author, category, featured media, and tags. Recently the REST api started returning the same `rest_url` value for any and all `_links` values, and subsequently the same root site data for any `_embedded` data.  So making a call to:

```
[GET] /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/123?_embed
```

Returns a structure like:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  ...,
  "_links": {
    "self":       [{ href: "<rest_url>" }],
    "collection": [{ href: "<rest_url>" }],
    "about":      [{ href: "<rest_url>" }],
    "author":     [{ href: "<rest_url>", embeddable: true }],
    "replies":    [{ href: "<rest_url>", embeddable: true }],
    ...,
  ]
}
```

Where `<rest_url>` is the value returned from the `rest_url` filter function:

```
add_filter('rest_url', function() {
  return `<rest_url>`;
});
```

I was able to restore functionality by updating the `rest_url` filter function, however I'm not sure what the root cause is, as this snippet does not cause the same issue locally or on other instances. The temporary solution looks like:

```
add_filter('rest_url', function( $path = ''){
  $url = str_replace("https://example.com//", '', $path);
  return "https://api.example.com/wp-json/{$url}";
});
```

What would cause the wordpress api to just return the `rest_url` for all `_links` values?

Comment: Have you tried asking the WordPress team directly? https://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: I've posted in the wordpress support forums but thought I would ask here as well @cabrerahector